# (this) isn't working; results in "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, squarespace

I have the following code which Chrome Inspector debugs with the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined":

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function countComments() {
    var mcount = '//api.moot.it/postcounts?path=/forum/comments:' + $(this).closest('article').attr('id').substring(8);
    $.getJSON(mcount, function(json) {
      var results = $('.entry-actions');
      $.each(json, function(key, val) {
        results.prepend('<a class="entry-comments" href="{permalink}#comments" title="Comments">' + val['size'] + ' Comments</a>');
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is with `(this)`, but I used it properly in a different script with `.click` and that code works just fine.

Is it because `(this)` can't be used on `.ready`? If so, how could I get this function to work with alternative code?

**EDIT with HTML:**

```
<article id="article-5344bff8e4b01730378236ff">
  <header class="entry-header cf">
    <p class="entry-actions"></p>
  </header>
    <div class="entry-title-wrapper">

    BLOG CONTENTS

    <div class="entry-injection">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function countComments() {
        var mcount = '//api.moot.it/postcounts?path=/forum/comments:' + $(this).closest('article').attr('id').substring(8);
        $.getJSON(mcount, function(json) {
          var results = $('.entry-actions');
          $.each(json, function(key, val) {
            results.prepend('<a class="entry-comments" href="{permalink}#comments" title="Comments">' + val['size'] + ' Comments</a>');
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
    </div>
    </div>
  </article>
```

Comment: What are you expecting `this` to be?

Comment: What is `this`? Have you tried to debug it? Did you try displaying the contents of it?

Comment: Please post your html part in your question.

Comment: I expect `this` to refer to the element containing the script, which in this case is a `<div>`. Ultimately what I'm trying to go for is to use the `<div>` as a reference point to select its own closest `<article>` parent from where it can get a uniquely-generated `id` attribute.

Comment: So why do not you pass the object in function and then use it??

Comment: Instead of using `$(this)`, just use a specific selector for finding what you want. I see you are looking for the closest article, so if you want the first article in the document you can write `$("article:first")` or `$("article").first()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in document ready function `this` points to document http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/J2r5V/

In this case you can't have any `article` parent element of document, so your function raise the error http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/J2r5V/1/.

I think you have to get all your `div` elements according on your needs, and for each of them execute the current function; in the context of the each `this` will be the correct element.

Comment: Ah, thank you for that explanation. I hadn't realized that `this` will point to the `document`.